# Sharepoint 2013 Workflows with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

I'm trying to create approval workflow with CSOM, I've found information on how to start or stop a workflow but I haven't found how to create and apply conditions through CSOM, is there any example or approach you know to accomplish this?

Comment: unless you are using third party tools, Workflows can only be managed with SSOM, What are you trying to accomplish? , can't you just use SP Designer Workflows ?

Comment: Hey there, by client requirement I must use only CSOM to accomplish this. I need to create approval workflows... So, are you saying is not possible working with workflows using CSOM?

Comment: not as a "workflow" 
what you need is a remote event receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start and stop the workflow by CSOM.  And get data from workflow by CSOM.

But we cannot add conditions into workflow by CSOM.

In other words, we cannot edit the workflow such as add conditions and actions by CSOM.

We can add conditions into workflow by SharePoint designer.